# Android how to make back button perform action on a the first click?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have back button reprogrammed like that:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    returnManager();
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when I touch it for the first time it doesn't do anything. After the first time, it works as intended and calls returnManager. Then, if I press some other buttons on the screen and press back again, it doesn't do anything for the first time but works on next touches. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Its hard to know the problem with the provided information, please provide more details. Like is there a base class and where are you overriding this behavior, how does the view hierarchy look like? in-terms of activities and its views like fragments etc.

Comment: It is not a big app, there is only 1 activity. Basically, there are buttons that show layout assigned to them and hide the rest. When user press back it gets reversed.

Comment: Are you sure you're not overriding the onKeyDown() method hiding the KEYCODE_BACK keydown events?

Comment: nope, I haven't touched onKeyDown, just onBackPressed()

Comment: @AdemirGotov does my code work?

Comment: @Curio Yes it works, just need 1 small modification. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strange solution:

```
int calls = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    calls++;
    if(calls==1)
    {
        returnManager();
        returnManager();
    }
    else
    {
        returnManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: that works, though I will have to add "calls = 0" to all other buttons actions because it doesn't work after you press other buttons, but thank you anyway! My question is why does it behave that way? Why does it skips first call?

Comment: One day I had the same problem and I solved it in this way. However, did you put any logs in onBackPressed() ?

Comment: No, I don't really need to. All I need this button to do is just to call returnManager(). I changed int to boolean so if it's false it calls returnManager 2 times and set it to true. Then, for other buttons actions, I've set it to false. That way, everytime you press onBack for the first time after creation or after user pressed some other buttons it works as intended.

Comment: I asked you if you put a log because it was helpful to know if the method really was called or not, because it's strange

Comment: I went through it with debugger and it seems to be called, but for some reason nothing happens, that's why it gets me weird